# Why is there an unanswered question in the Shabbat Musaph Kedusha?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

In the Shabbat Kedusha, there is an unanswered question (Nusach Ashkenaz):

> כבודו מלא עולם. משרתיו שואלים זה לזה איה מקום כבודו

"His honor fills the world. His (G-d's) Servants ask each other, 'Where is the place of His honor?'"

It seems that G-d's servants are never getting an answer to this question. And, when we say Kedusha each Shabbat, we relay the same unanswered question that they ask. What's the point of doing this all the time? If we already know that there is no answer, why do we keep relaying the same question, or for that matter, why do G-d's servants keep asking this?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 4):

What do you mean it's unanswered? It's actually a [self-answered question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer):

> כבודו מלא עולם. משרתיו שואלים זה לזה איה מקום כבודו? לעומתם
>
> His honor fills the world. His (G-d's) Servants ask each other, 'Where is the place of His honor? Opposite them.'

Comment: clever .... :-) Your link is a bit misleading, though. You answered my question!

Comment: If you had posted this answer and it didn't get any votes you know what it would be? An unanswered, self-answered question!

Answer (score 1):

Chazal say that the Malachim can only say the Shem after the words, קדוש קדוש קדוש, but we do after two, שמע ישראל.

Therefore, after mentioning קדוש, and about to say ברוך כבוד ה'‏ we are justifying in what way we are better than the angels.

The idea is simple. *We* know that כבודו מלא עולם, while they are still wondering איה. So, aren't we more worthy to say the Shem after two words?